# What is 女斗士 and when can I use this?

Tags: translation

女斗士 was used to pertain to a courageous female based on what I read,  but I wanted to know how am I able to use this word and when?

Answer (score 3):

女— female/woman

斗士— fighter

So 女斗士 literally means “female warrior”. You would use this term the same way you use 斗士, since “female” is just an additional detail.

Example:

> 冠状病毒疫情在全球肆虐，各国护士为了保障人民的安全，都如女斗士般在前线努力奋斗着。
>
> The coronavirus situation is globally rampant; nurses all over the world are fighting in the frontlines, just like female warriors, to ensure the safety of the people.

(I made the assumption that the vast majority of nurses are female)

Comment: Would this term be appropriate for describing female athletes?

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25 it can be used figuratively

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use 斗士 only, to avoid any despection over women. Emphasis on the gender is admitting women usually cannot be warriors. In different aspect of life, humans can be courageous despite of gender.